# I am having problems reading multiple txt files

Tags: python, ip, glob

I am having a trouble when I try to read multiple text files in python.
I'm trying to get only IP addresses from text files. When I try with a single text file, it works fine. However, when I copy more than one text file to the folder, I only get the output of the first file.

```
import os
import re
import glob



path = "file_direction"
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:(?:1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\d|0?[1-9]\d|0?0?\d)\.){3}(?:1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\d|0?[1-9]\d|0?0?\d)')
valid = []
invalid = []



for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt")):
    with open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
        string = fh.readlines()


for line in string:
    line = line.rstrip()
    result = pattern.search(line)

    # valid IP addresses
    if result:
        valid.append(line)

    # invalid IP addresses
    else:
        invalid.append(line)

# displaying the IP addresses
print("Valid IPs")
print(valid)
print("Invalid IPs")
print(invalid)
```

Comment: Obviously the second `for` loop indentation is off - it should be nested inside the first one. As a side note - don't use `string` as name, it's a module from standard library.

Comment: Are you sure you're not only getting the output of the **last** file? How do you know the order of the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a problem with indentation, your current code runs only on the last file.

correct code:

```
import os
import re
import glob

path = "file_direction"
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:(?:1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\d|0?[1-9]\d|0?0?\d)\.){3}(?:1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\d|0?[1-9]\d|0?0?\d)')
valid = []
invalid = []

for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt")):
    with open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
        string = fh.readlines()

    for line in string:
        line = line.rstrip()
        result = pattern.search(line)

        # valid IP addresses
        if result:
            valid.append(line)

        # invalid IP addresses
        else:
            invalid.append(line)

# displaying the IP addresses
print("Valid IPs")
print(valid)
print("Invalid IPs")
print(invalid)
```